# Javascript switch statement with includes method

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-5

Okay, bit of a weird one, either what I'm doing here is a bit more complicated than I thought or my brain isn't working, but I'm trying to use a switch statement to check whether a string includes something and then run a block of code...

```js
const msg = 'hash-test'

switch (msg) {

  case msg.includes('foo'):
    // do something
    break;

  case msg.includes('hash-'):
    // do something else
    break;

}
```

Trying to figure out why my `msg.includes('hash-')` case statement isn't running since my string does contain **hash**

Any thoughts?

Comment: `switch (true)`?

Comment: `switch (true)` would do that, since `includes` only returns `true` or `false` and you want to match the one case that returns `true`. However, consider `[ "foo", "hash-" ].find((keyword) => msg.includes(keyword))` instead.

Comment: Personally I don't like such `switch(true)` stuff because it;s harder to read and maintain

Comment: why would you want to use a switch statement to check if a string contains a substring?

Comment: You are trying to use a frozen fish to hammer in nails. Switch works by evaluating one expression and checking that against string or integers cases. You can't evaluate an expression as a case statement.

Comment: @k0pernikus _“You can't evaluate an expression as a case statement.”_ — What is this statement based on? Of course you can put expressions after `case`. See the [specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#prod-CaseClause).

Comment: @user4642212 Let me rephrase: `msg.includes('hash-')` will be evaluated. Namely to either false and true. Yet the `msg` on which the switch is based upon will always remain a string and hence the switch statement will always run into its default case. The behavior the OP intended is not possible though.

Comment: @k0pernikus - Yes it is: By using `switch (true)` as user464whatever said, with exactly the case statements shown in the question. Desirable? Almost never. Possible? Yes.

Answer (score 2):

`switch(msg)` compares the string `msg` to the boolean `case msg.includes('foo')`, which is never strictly equal.

So: don't use a `switch` statement here!

```
const msg = 'hash-test'

if (msg.includes('foo')) {
    // do something
} else if (msg.includes('hash-')) {
    // do something else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const msg = 'hash-test'

switch (msg.includes('foo') || msg.includes('hash-')) {
  case msg.includes('foo'):
    // do something
    console.log("heloo")
    break;
  case msg.includes('hash-'):
    // do something else
    console.log('world');
    break;
}
```